Manage whitelist dns access inbound and outbound of ubuntu
We would like to manage whitelist dns access inbound and outbound of ubuntu. Others dns not listed then will be blocked.
Any suggestion to resolve this issue would be very much appreciated!
Thanks!

This question is similar to: Allow Ubuntu Server Access only from specific IP's. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

What version of Ubuntu are you using?

@graham: Thanks. However I prefer manage via dns/domain instead of IP.

@DavidDE: Version of ubuntu that we are using that is 24.04
